# Is it possible to have 2 different font size within a PBI card visual

Tags: powerbi

I managed to work out concatenate two measures within one power bi card visual, but is it possible to make the font smaller just for the value in the bracket in the formula?

If yes, how?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct option for that but always there is workaround. The solution is-

> Show your first line in 1 card visual

> Show your second line in another card visual

> Now place a rectangle shape around

> Now select all 3 visual and group them

This way you can format your values in different card as per your requirement. Here below is a sample output-

[image]

Comment: thanks, that was my plan b too :)  just wanted to see if it's possible to do it all in one.   Actually I did another work around, I put a transparent image over the main value so when user hover over it reveals a tooltip page

Comment: Nice to hear that.